# TensorFlow model with time series data, having different input shapes for training and prediction

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series, data-science

I am having a somewhat decent working neural net, utilising mostly LSTM, Dropout and Dense layers. I usually use it for sales prediction only but now my issue is that I'd like to train and predict with datasets of different shapes.

I have several columns showing marketing spending per channel, as well as sales for different products. Below you find an image, illustrating the dataset. Now, the orange data (marketing channels and product sales) are supposed to be the training data. When I do a many-to-many prediction, I could just forecast all the columns, like I do when I've got a dataset containing only sales.

But I already *know* the marketing spendings for the future, because it already is planned ahead. Now, for that I could just use pystats (OLS for example) but LSTM are really good at remembering the past marketing spendings and sales.

Actual Question:
is there a way to utilise a tensorflow neural net with a different input shape on training and test data? Test data in this case would be either actual test data or already the actual future.
Or any other comparable model? Unfortunately, I have not found any solution during my research.

Thanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: The input shape won't change (you can't do that). But you could probably just append the real values on at each time step if that is the case.

Comment: Yeah, thought as much :/ For now, I used RaggedTensors to do something similar but the implementation is whacky as s. I just went for LSTM based approach.